# What amount of JsDoc is supported in Google Sheets custom functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jsdoc, custom-function

Google implies that JsDoc is supported:

> Custom functions will appear in this list if their script includes a
>   JsDoc @customfunction tag, as in the DOUBLE() example below.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

But it doesn't seem that JsDoc is supported in full, and I can't find the documentation that shows what is supported and not.

I'm particularly looking for **a way to document that a parameter for a custom function is optional**. Like this, for value2:

[image]

Image courtesy of: https://yagisanatode.com/2018/08/24/google-apps-script-how-to-make-a-custom-function-to-use-in-google-sheets/

Using JsDoc, you should be able to do the following, based on this source:
https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#optional-parameters-and-default-values

```
/**
 * @param {number} [value2] - Additional numbers or ranges to add to value1.
 */
```

And, with a default value:

```
/**
 * @param {number} [value2=100] - Additional numbers or ranges to add to value1.
 */
```

But I tested this in Google sheets, and none of this works. Not even the suggested Google Closure Compiler syntax (in case that should work):

```
/**
 * @param {number=} value2 - Additional numbers or ranges to add to value1.
 */
```

Currently I have resorted to the less elegant:

```
/**
 * @param {number} value2 - [OPTIONAL] Additional numbers or ranges to add to value1.
 */
```

So, where can I find the documentation over what part of JsDoc is supported in Google Sheets?

Bonus points if you can show a way to document the optional parameter using JsDoc that achieves the desired result from the screenshot (which is better than my current inelegant solution).

Comment: Side note: By bonus points, do you mean a bounty?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JsDoc optional arguments feature doesn't seem to be supported for Sheets custom functions, but no official documentation can be found for this.

I'd suggest you to file a Feature Request in [this component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/191640) to ask for this functionality, or at least to document in more detail what functionality is supported.

#### Update:

A Feature Request regarding this was submitted in Issue Tracker by OP:

- [Issue #156230902: The level of JsDoc support is not documented (for Sheets custom functions)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156230902)

Anyone who want to keep track of this can click the star on the top left on the referenced page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not very familiar with submitting issue requests there, but now I did submit this one: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156230902

Comment: @Magne Thank you for reporting this. I updated my answer with the link you referenced, so that people with your same question can find this easily.