# How do I pass unspecified number of variables to Google Apps Script Custom Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a Google Sheet. In this sheet, I want to run a custom function to do a complex calculation. This calculation will be based on values from other cells in other sheet tabs. For that reason, I want to be able to pass in a number of variables that is likely to change in the future.

I noticed the [SUM function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en) allows for optional parameters. The optional values are "repeatable". This is the behavior I want to reproduce in my custom function, repeatable/optional parameters. How does the SUM function allow for repeatable/optional parameters? How can I do the same in a custom function?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd pass the repeatable parameters in one array, in this use case (especially if you are passing other variables as well). Not sure how to enforce overloading google apps script functions, I think it might not be possible but my research on the topic was back before V8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Apps Script, How to include optional arguments in custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843768/in-apps-script-how-to-include-optional-arguments-in-custom-functions)

Comment: You can pass parameters in an array and then test their length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [function rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
function COMPLEXSUM(...args) {
  let sum = 0  

  args.forEach(x => {
    sum += x
  })
  
  return sum
}
```

or if you want some parameters to be required and additionally some optional ones:

```
function COMPLEXSUM(param1, param2, ...args) {
  let sum = param1 + param2
  
  return args.length === 0 ? sum : sum + args.reduce((pre, curr) => {
    return pre + curr;
  })
}
```